# Navigation item disappears with popover

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I have created a popup displaying a list in which I send the text to another viewcontroller, but when I close the popup, the Navigation Item disappears, and I have already searched for nothing to solve this problem. The code that sends the selected list item in the popover is this:

```
Shared.shared.filialNome = self.filiais[indexPath.row].razaoSocial
self.recebeCodigo = self.filiais[indexPath.row].codigo
Shared.shared.codigoFilial = self.recebeCodigo

let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AniversarioViewController") as! AniversarioViewController
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Type of following = Modal
I have tried to call Present as Popover but the error persists, it seems that it does not close the VC completely, somebody can help me.

[Before opening the popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbQD9.png) and
[After opening the popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K03H5.png)

Comment: This is behavior that seems to have changed somewhere in iOS 10/11. Just use the setNavigationBarHidden method to override this where you need it.

Comment: it is possible to share project. will check one technique on ios 11

Comment: how you are dismissing the popup??

Comment: igraczech, I already used the method, but I still did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, as you are presenting the view controller (and ViewControllers do not have navigation item until we embed it in navigation controller).
So you can embed the same ViewController in navigation controller in storyboard and then get the reference for that navigation controller and present the navigation controller like

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourNavigationControllerIdentifier") as! UINavigationController
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or if you don't want to embed you can do programmatically like

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AniversarioViewController") as! AniversarioViewController
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: newViewController)
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hello, the second option worked perfectly, but the actions of the Navigation buttons stop working, how do I turn them on too? Thank you very much

Comment: sorry but which buttons you are talking about. I think you may need to add Bar buttons in your newViewController class for its navigation controller